# Spring-boot + Oauth2: CSRF ~ Restful API

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, csrf-protection, oauth-2.0

i'm learning Spring-boot and Oauth2. I  have a few problems.

i'm implementing protection against CSRF

```
.csrf()
                .requireCsrfProtectionMatcher(new AndRequestMatcher(
                    new NegatedRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/test", HttpMethod.OPTIONS.toString()))
                ));
```

this is working fine but when i try to access another path on my API i'm getting this message.

```
"error": "access_denied"
"error_description": "Invalid CSRF Token 'null' was found on the request parameter '_csrf' or header 'X-CSRF-TOKEN'."
```

i tried to set the cookie with the JSESSIONID on my request but didn't work

```
Status
403 Prohibido Show explanation Loading time: 22
Request headers 
Accept: application/json
Origin: chrome-extension://hgmloofddffdnphfgcellkdfbfbjeloo
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/47.0.2526.106 Safari/537.36
Authorization: Bearer 4abe8cbc-a528-4d52-8e20-a0aa198056d2
Content-Type: application/json 
DNT: 1
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept-Language: es-ES,es;q=0.8,en;q=0.6,und;q=0.4
Cookie: JSESSIONID=3DB726CA18F6628719703891B7DCA0A2
Response headers 
Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1 
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
Pragma: no-cache
Expires: 0 
X-Frame-Options: DENY
Cache-Control: no-store 
Pragma: no-cache 
Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8 
Transfer-Encoding: chunked 
Date: Tue, 05 Jan 2016 03:59:45 GMT
```

Also i tried to set my CSRF filter on my project, was worst, this didn't get me the Cookie with the JSESSIONID. Literally do nothing

```
@Configuration
@Order(SecurityProperties.ACCESS_OVERRIDE_ORDER)
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

@Autowired
CustomAuthenticationProvider customAuthenticationProvider;

@Override
protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth.authenticationProvider(customAuthenticationProvider);
}

@Override
@Bean
public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
    return super.authenticationManagerBean();
}

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.httpBasic().and().authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/test").permitAll().anyRequest()
            .authenticated()
            .and().csrf()
            .csrfTokenRepository(csrfTokenRepository()).and()
            .addFilterAfter(csrfHeaderFilter(), CsrfFilter.class);
}

private Filter csrfHeaderFilter() {
    return new OncePerRequestFilter() {
        @Override
        protected void doFilterInternal(
                HttpServletRequest request,
                HttpServletResponse response,
                FilterChain filterChain)
                throws ServletException, IOException {
            CsrfToken csrf = (CsrfToken) request.getAttribute(CsrfToken.class.getName());
            if (csrf != null) {
                Cookie cookie = WebUtils.getCookie(request, "XSRF-TOKEN");
                String token = csrf.getToken();
                if (cookie == null || token != null
                        && !token.equals(cookie.getValue())) {
                    cookie = new Cookie("XSRF-TOKEN", token);
                    cookie.setPath("/");
                    response.addCookie(cookie);
                }
            }
            filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
        }
    };
}

private CsrfTokenRepository csrfTokenRepository() {
    HttpSessionCsrfTokenRepository repository = new HttpSessionCsrfTokenRepository();
    repository.setHeaderName("X-XSRF-TOKEN");
    return repository;
}
}
```

Any idea what i'm doing wrong?

**EDIT** i've found a partial solution i think, but now i have a few questions.

**Solution:** 
made my CrsfTokenRepository a `@Bean`

```
@Bean
public CsrfTokenRepository csrfTokenRepository() {
    HttpSessionCsrfTokenRepository repository = new HttpSessionCsrfTokenRepository();
    repository.setHeaderName("X-XSRF-TOKEN");
    return repository;
}
```

made a whole class only for my `CsrfHeaderFilter`

```
public class CsrfHeaderFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {

@Override
protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    CsrfToken csrf = (CsrfToken) request.getAttribute(CsrfToken.class
            .getName());
    if (csrf != null) {
        Cookie cookie = WebUtils.getCookie(request, "XSRF-TOKEN");
        String token = csrf.getToken();
        if (cookie == null || token != null && !token.equals(cookie.getValue())) {
            cookie = new Cookie("XSRF-TOKEN", token);
            cookie.setPath("/");
            response.addCookie(cookie);
        }
    }
    filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
}

}
```

and moved my configuration in `WebSecurityConfiguration` to my `Oauth2Configuration`

```
@Configuration
@EnableResourceServer
protected static class ResourceServerConfiguration extends ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private CustomLogoutSuccessHandler customLogoutSuccessHandler;

    @Autowired
    private CsrfTokenRepository csrfTokenRepository;

    @Override
    public void configure(ResourceServerSecurityConfigurer resources) {
        resources
                .resourceId(RESOURCE_ID);
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                // Logout
                .logout()
                .logoutUrl("/oauth/logout")
                .logoutSuccessHandler(customLogoutSuccessHandler)
                .and()
                //Session management
                .sessionManagement()
                .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
                .and()
                //URI's to verify
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/test").hasRole("ADMIN")
                .antMatchers("/users").authenticated()
                .antMatchers("/**").authenticated()
                .antMatchers("/productos").hasAnyRole("ADMIN, VENDEDOR")
                .and()
                .addFilterAfter(new CsrfHeaderFilter(), CsrfFilter.class)
                .csrf()
                .csrfTokenRepository(csrfTokenRepository);
    }
}
```

**My questions are:**

- This solution is fine? is a good practice?
- the JSESSIONID and the XSRF-Token dont need to be attached in my angularjs request?

Comment: have you tried passing the token as part of your request header? i think u need to do something like : Bearer <token>

Comment: yeah, was the first i did it

Comment: Possibly this question is related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36745521/how-could-i-use-csrf-in-spring-security/36890677#36890677 ?